# Are the Firebase Auth methods asynchronous tasks or not?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to do a login and a register in Firebase, and I have the Firebase auth methods inside an async task class but it's not work properly. If I remove the async task class everything is ok. Sorry if my question is stupid but I don't know what to do. Should I remove the async task class, or the error is elsewhere ? Thanks.

Comment: *Should I remove the async task class* - yes

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks for your response.